# Can I call the Super Constructor and pass the Class name in java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have the super class `Vehicle`, with it's subclasses `Plane` and `Car`. The vehicle extends from a class which has a `final string name;` field, which can only be set from the constructor.

I want to set this field to the class' name, so the name of Car would be Car, Plane would be Plane and Vehicle would be Vehicle. First thing I thought:

```
public Vehicle() {
    super(getClass().getSimpleName()); //returns Car, Plane or Vehicle (Subclass' name)
}
```

But this gives me the error: `Cannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor`.

How can I still set the `name` field to the class name, without manually passing it in as a String?

Comment: Why? The class can get its own name any time, it doesn't need to store it in a field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to do that.

You can just call `getClass().getSimpleName()` directly from the base constructor.

Comment: The problem with this is that I can not modify the base class, since this is part of an API (Libgdx library). The name String must be passed through a constructor, and futher there's no more write access to it.

Comment: Well, I guess that this answers my question best, even tough it doesn't apply in my situation. I now just pass the name-String manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
   //Vehicle constructor
    public Vehicle() {
        super(Vehicle.class.getSimpleName()); 
    }

    //Plane constructor
    public Plane(){
        super(Plane.class.getSimpleName());
    }
```

Comment: This will always return "Vehicle", and not the name of the possible Subclass.

Comment: Put the subclass name in each subclass constructor. I edited the answer.

Comment: But that's what I didn't want: having to define every name manually. I liked the getSimpleName so much, for it gets the actual subclass name, so I could have one call in the superclass and it just gets the 'actual' object's type.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler told you, you can't call instance methods as part of the invocation of the "super()" method.

You can however call static methods.  Also, while in the super constructor code itself, you can always call "getClass()" and it will return the actual instance type.

```
public class A {
  public A() {
      System.out.println("class: " + getClass().getName());
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public B() {
      super();
  }
}

new A(); --> "class: A"
new B(); --> "class: B"
```